# mail() function doesn't not send infomation to my email

Tags: php, email

**Here is my code:**

```
 <?php
    header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

    $to = 'example@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Message to the site';

    $realname = htmlspecialchars($_POST['realname']);
    $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
    $msg = htmlspecialchars($_POST['msg']);

    $headers = 'From: example@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: example@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();


    mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers) or die("Error!");
    echo 'Thank you! :)';
?>
```

Could somebody explaing me - why this code does not work properly? 
I meant that, when I click button submit, it send the email, but I could not include `$msg` in it and I don't know why.

Comment: Did you check whether there is a value for msg variable?

Comment: Try setting some garbage value in msg varible. Like $msg = "Hello";

Comment: Did you get "Error!" as output? or do you get "Thank you" and no Email?

Comment: @user3661795 Your code is running, put some string in variable $msg like $msg="This is the message" as told by Thusitha and then try also check what value are you getting in  variable $_POST['msg'].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add :

```
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html';
```

Add this line under $headers and than check i hope this will work for you...